# How do I have a Dict accept an input (having a dictionary accept an int input so pulling it for a later use will be easier) python

Tags: python, dictionary, input

As I was typing this I got this to work the `#Dict = {'a': ab, 'b': ba}` is what I was trying to do first where I have the ab input and ba input inserted in the Dict which I'll get into later

```
 ab = int(input("type number here:"))
 ba = int(input("type number here:"))
 #Dict = {'a': ab, 'b': ba}
 Dict = {'Correct': 'you are correct', 'Incorrect': 'you are incorrect'}
 sum = ab + ba
 if (sum == 3):
    print(Dict['Correct'])
 else:
    print(Dict['Incorrect'])
```

But what I'm trying to do now is set it up so I can use inputs for a dictionary so I can pull from that dicionary easily and more than once to use them for something else if nedded.

In this case I'm trying to make it so I can input two numbers ex. 3 and 7, then take those two and add them together and if the sum is equal to a number it will output "you are correct" but anything else it outputs "you are incorrect".

this is the code I tried with the knolage I have. the `#insert inputs here` in the Dict are goals of what I'm trying to accomplish, and the `#dont know if this would work` above the `sum == a + b` is there because that is all I could think of to set a value that would detect if the value was or not.

```
 a = int()
 b = int()
 Dict = {
 'a': #insert input here,
 'b': #insert input here
}
 Dict = {
 'Correct': 'you are correct',
 'Incorrect': 'you are incorrect'
}
#dont know if this would work
    sum == a + b 
    if (sum == 3):
        print(Dict['Correct'])
    else:
        print(Dict['Incorrect'])
```

p.s. I'm new to python this is actually my first project, and I know the first and second code don't make sense in commperison to each other because I don't really want to go through the process of rewriting it, so if (you all will forgive me for my laziness) you can just help with the second one I would appreciate it, Thank You.

Comment: What is the purpose of using a `dict` for this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You could have a dictionary whose keys are different inputs, and it prints the message corresponding to that input. But since they can enter any input, it might not be one of the keys, so it doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @PacketLoss 1. The ```dict``` is being used so i can assign a number value to AH Ace Of Hearts and so i can pick the cards randomly. 2. this is for a card counting trainer so i can learn to count cards.